# how do I skip a RewriteRule if REQUEST_URI is a specific directory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a http connection to https, but not for the rss directory

```
# redirect to SSL connection
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# can't get the next line to work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(rss)($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rss/
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that should work. But for me, it doesn't. :-/ I will create another question with more detail.

Comment: @clark hmm, that's strange! What happens instead? Do you get redirected anyway? Can you show an example URL?